# How to set crossOrigin anonymous

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I have the following js code that captures a video and draws a canvas.
Controller code :

```
$scope.capture = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    //video.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    }
```

I do run the above function after file is uploaded and video is playing as so:

```
 var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#file-5' ) );
        myEl.bind('change', function(e) {
        $scope.handleFileSelect = function() {
          //DO STUFF : uploads file and plays it in template
          //Then I run the capture function to draw canvas thumbnail
          //Plan is to check if the  $scope.handleFileSelect(); has finished executing.
          $interval (function(){
                    $scope.capture();
          }, 5500); 
        }
      $scope.handleFileSelect();
});
```

And my template view:

```
<video id="video" preload="metadata"  height="400" width="100%" autoplay="1" src="{{trustSrc(upload.downloadURL)}}" type="video/mp4" controls muted></video><br/>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

This draws the canvas image.

The problem is I can't get the dataUrl

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') returns an error

```
Error: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

From research online, there are suggestions of using crossOrigin="anonymous"

I tried to set it on the video tag, it won't work. 
Any ideas as to how I can set this up?

Comment: Last time I checked some browsers still taint the canvas after drawing cross-origin video -- even with 'anonymous'. Also,  **`crossOrigin="anonymous"` is not enough!**. You must also configure the video server to send the appropriate access-control headers in the response.

Comment: Is the comment in your snippet the only way you have set the crossOrigin attribute ? You have to set this attribute **before** setting the `src` one, or directly in the markup. Otherwise, the browser will already have done the request as a non cross-origin one, and you will effectively taint your canvas. Also, ditto to @markE, you have to be sure that your server is well configured to send the proper *Allow Origin* headers in the response.

Comment: I am using firebase which Allows Origin Headers. But I still get the error.

Comment: As I said, you have to set it before the browser makes the request to the server, try to include it in your template markup directly.

Comment: @Kaiido When I do, the weird this is, the video refuses to even play or show. And it logs no errors.

Comment: Then it's not weird at all, it's just that your server is not responding with the correct Allow Origin headers for your video file. You can find out some explanations on how to configure various server configs on [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/). Once done, keep the attribute in your markup, and you'll be out of this nightmare ;-)